# Как отключить доступ к GitHub репозиторию?

Tags: git, github, аутентификация

Создал локальный репозиторий, затем создал удаленный на GitHub.

Сделал привязку локального с удаленным:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

Запушил с локального на удаленный файлы.

Теперь хочу полностью прервать доступ локального компа к удаленному репозиторию.

Удалил в GitHub -> Settings -> Emails адрес почты юзера под которым пушил файлы.

Затем удалил привязку:

```
git remote remove origin
```

Но если заново ввожу на текущем компе

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

у меня снова полный доступ к удаленному репозиторию без необходимости ввода пароля. Могу снова делать push и pull.

Как мне прервать эту связь чтоб GitHub не давал повторный доступ текущему компу к удаленному репозиторию без какой-либо аутентификации?

Comment: вам нужно не пользователя и репозиторий удалять, а credentials

Comment: В **Диспетчер учетных данных** удалил запись git:github.com. Теперь при попытке подключения к удаленному репо запрашивает аутентификацию через браузер. Если я правильно понял виной всему приложение **Git Credential Manager** которое устанавливается вместе с **Git** для Windows10. Вот здесь [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182847/how-do-i-disable-git-credential-manager-for-windows] люди обсуждают как его отключить/удалить. Но бегло изучив вопрос у меня пока не получилось удалить это приложение.